# How to disable only the expander togglebutton WPF

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

I'm trying to disable the expander togglebutton dynamically using IsEnabled property and when I do that, the whole content is disabled also.
I want to disable the togglebutton while keeping the content controls enable.

Thank's

Elad

Comment: can you post your xaml and the code where you set the IsEnabled property

Answer (score 1):

Make a copy of the style template for the Expander, find the toggle button within the template and set your IsEnabled property to it specifically instead of to the Expander control itself.

So, in Expression Blend right-click an Expander control and go to Edit Template -> Edit a Copy and save a copy of your template wherever you like, in most cases a resource dictionary is the best idea. Find the button object in the template that is your expander button and put your IsEnabled property there. Then just apply that style template to your expander control like `<Expander Style="{StaticResource YourNewExpanderTemplateName}.../>` so that the IsEnabled dependency property applies just to the button object instead of the entire control.

Give it a shot. Cheers!

Comment: Hi,
Thank's for your help! You wrote to put the IsEnabled property in the togglebutton, how do I do that?

Comment: Ya no worries, if you have the template already copied out go to it for edit. Find the toggle button object and add your IsEnabled="{Binding}" straight to its xaml tag so like <ToggleButton IsEnabled="{Binding}".../> then just wire up your conditional binding to its state to show True or False as you wish. Make sense?

Comment: Thank's! it works :)
I now have a problem that the button is disable but his style remains the same, I tried to set is with a trigger but it doesn't work, any idea?

Comment: So the Expander button is disabled but it still looks active? If that's the case, go back to your template, right click the expander button and do Edit Template -> Edit a Copy to make a copy of the button template in Expression Blend. Then click your "States" tab top left corner and go to your "Disabled" State, if the button there still looks active in its Disabled State, Go back to your "Base" state and... (next comment)

Comment: make an ellipse shape over it with white background at 50% opacity and set its visibility to "Collapsed" at Base State, and "Visible" on its Disabled State, this will make it appear disabled. If I understood correctly?

Comment: I solved it in a different way,
but thank's a lot for your help!
You are awesome!!!

Comment: Glad I could help, make sure to mark questions as answered if they helped you. Best of luck! :)